# How to add or disable(remove)md-disable-backdrop pragmatically in md-sidenav

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Is it possible to remove `md-disable-backdrop` attribute from HTML ?

The `md-sidenav` `md-disable-backdrop` attribute is not added when i open the side navigation. The i make a selection from the form i just displayed in the side navigation and now i want to add the `md-disable-backdrop` attribute to the `md-sidenav`

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id="right" class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-4dp" md-disable-backdrop id="rightSideNav">
```

Comment: Your title says "remove" but your content says "add". Which one is it?

Comment: Let me update the title. I want both, first i want to add it and then remove it as mentioned in the details. Thanks for pointing out !

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/XjVwaj?editors=1010#0)

If you inspect the `md-sidenav` element you will see the `md-disable-backdrop` attribute toggled. Note: this **won't** toggle the backdrop, which is what I suspect you actually want.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-content flex="" layout-padding="">
    <div layout="column" layout-fill="" layout-align="top center">
      <div>
        <md-button ng-click="toggleRight()" ng-hide="isOpenRight($event)" class="md-primary">
          Toggle right
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div flex=""></div>
  </md-content>
  <md-sidenav id="mySideNav" class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="right">
    <md-content ng-controller="RightCtrl" layout-padding="">
      <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary">
        Close Sidenav Right
      </md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="toggleMdDisableBackdrop()">Toggle md-disable-backdrop</md-button>
    </md-content>
  </md-sidenav>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular
  .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $mdSidenav, $element) {
    $scope.mdDisableBackdrop = false;
    $scope.sideNav = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#mySideNav'));

    $scope.toggleRight = function() {
      $mdSidenav('right')
        .toggle()
        .then(function () {
      });
    }
  })
  .controller('RightCtrl', function ($scope, $mdSidenav) {
    $scope.close = function () {
      $mdSidenav('right').close();
    };

    $scope.toggleMdDisableBackdrop = function () {
      if ($scope.mdDisableBackdrop) {
        $scope.sideNav.removeAttr('md-disable-backdrop');
      }
      else {
        $scope.sideNav.attr("md-disable-backdrop", "true");
      }
      $scope.mdDisableBackdrop = !$scope.mdDisableBackdrop;
    };
  });
```